# Loops in android

Tags: java, android, math

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to implement a simple maths game. I've gotten as far as generating random questions and being able to validate answers, but I want to limit the game to ten questions and to display the users score after the final question. I'm a novice programmer and from what I understand I will require some form of loop. Any code examples or general help/advice would be fantastic, thanks.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.keypad_hash:

    checkAnswer();
    getQuestion();


    break;

case R.id.keypad_1:

    editText.append(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));

    break;


case R.id.keypad_2:

    editText.append(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));

    break;



case R.id.keypad_3:

    editText.append(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));

    break;

case R.id.keypad_4:

editText.append(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));

break;

case R.id.keypad_5:

editText.append(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));

break;

case R.id.keypad_6:

editText.append(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));

break;

case R.id.keypad_7:

editText.append(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));

break;

case R.id.keypad_8:

editText.append(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));

break;

case R.id.keypad_9:

editText.append(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));

break;
case R.id.keypad_0:

editText.append(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));

break;
case R.id.keypad_delete:

    if (editText.getText().length() > 0) {
        editText.getText().delete(editText.getText().length() - 1,
                editText.getText().length());
    }

break;

case R.id.keypad_minus:

editText.append(String.valueOf(v.getTag()));


break;

  } 
}

public void getQuestion(){

    random1 = (int)(Math.random()*100);
    random2 = (int)(Math.random()*10);

    int i1 = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(i1 == 1){
    question = (random1 + "+" + random2);
    correctAnswer = random1 + random2;
    editTextEquation.setText(question);
    }
    if(i1 == 2){
    question = (random1 + "-" +random2);
    correctAnswer = random1 - random2;
    editTextEquation.setText(question);

    }
    if(i1 == 3){
    question = random1 + "/" +random2;
    correctAnswer = random1 / random2;
    editTextEquation.setText(question);

    }
    if(i1 == 4){
    question = (random1 + "*" +random2);
    correctAnswer = random1 * random2;
    editTextEquation.setText(question);


    }
    }

    }




    public void checkAnswer(){
       int mm = 0;
        //answer = editText.getText().toString();
        mm = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());

        if (mm == correctAnswer){

          score++;
        scoredisplay.setText("" + score);


    }
        else {

        score--;
        scoredisplay.setText("" + score);
    }




 }


}
```

Comment: I think what you need is a Java tutorial.

Comment: Voting to close. The not-a-real-question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might not need a loop the way you built it.

```
this.counter = 10;

...

case R.id.keypad_hash:
  checkAnswer();
  this.counter--;
  if( this.counter > 0 ){
    getQuestion();
  } else {
    scoreText.setText(score);
  }
  break;
```

Comment: This is a better approach rather than a loop for Android. Thus, my answer was more general.

Comment: just make sure, there is no more clicking going on, once `counter <= 0`

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter in your program to keep the number of questions that you have displayed.
e.g.

```
int counter = 0;

while (counter < 10){

//Show and validate your questions here
counter++;
}

//Print out the score
```

You can find some simple examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop#Java.2C_C.23.2C_D)

In addition to these, learning [Java basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) would be good for your before starting Android development